# MMONOOB tag request

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we start using a tag called "MMONOOB" or something less direct to indicate that a post is asking "HOW DO I WRITE MY UBER SWEET MMO, NO I HAVEN'T DONE ANY WORK YET, HELP ME?". Then I could just add those to the ignore list and be happy.

Comment: Why don't we just *close* them instead...

Comment: In my experience the mmo tag cover pretty much what the mmonoob tag would, there is no need to start arguing whether or not people are noobs when they have already announced that they are developing an mmo, and by the way don't know basic pathfinding or something like that.

Comment: Well done for inciting a flame war each time the tag is used .. because thats a good use of tagging right??

Answer (score 10):

This tag should not exist because it is primarily identifying a poor kind of question that is undesirable. If it is undesirable, the proper course of action would be to vote-to-close the question under an appropriate reason. Without the ability to vote to close, one can flag them for attention, or just not visit the question altogether.

Fact is, though, such a tag is not intuitive to new users (who will be the ones who keep asking such questions). This means that such users are not likely to ever add that tag on their own, so you would *still* see those questions. Existing users who visit such a question, again, should be voting to close or otherwise dealing with the question, not adding the tag and being on their merry way.

Comment: I think I was tired when I wrote this, but I was referring to the questions that technically fit the site. They're useful to others in that person's situation. Anyway I was tired, bad question sorry. The thought was to have users like us edit and retag with that so other's don't have to bother seeing it.

Comment: @brandon Can you give some concrete examples, then? Though all things said, tags should be designed for people to find things as often as they are for people to pass them by.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental problem with such a request is that you're asking for a meta tag.  Meta tags are explicitly discouraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

[mmonoob](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmonoob) wouldn't describe the *content* of the question other than being a meta tag for "beginner" mmo questions.  Which would be the same thing as tagging a question as [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) and [mmo](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmo).  And since the [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag is destroyed on sight, you can see where I'm going with this.